# How to pass a table name as variable to a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have inherited a bunch of stored procedures basically as a shell and inside the quotes is this huge dynamic SQL with lots of conditions, calculations and case statements, however the table name in the `FROM` clause within this dynamic SQL changes every quarter.

Now before I get flamed, I like to simply say that I inherited them, how it was designed was before me. So each quarter when a call is made out to these stored procedures, it comes with the actual table name passed as a parameter and then the dynamic SQL concatenates the table name.

The problem with this approach is that, with each run over time, the prior designers simply tacked on more criteria as conditions and calculations. But the dynamic SQL string has a length limit to it. Further it becomes quite difficult to maintain and debug.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE .....
    @dynSQL1 = 'SELECT......
            FROM' + strTblName + '
            WHERE.....   
            GROUP BY....' 
     ...
     EXEC @dynSQL1
 GO
```

However, I like to ask you all, is there a way to turn this stored procedure with this huge dynamic SQL string into a plain vanilla stored procedure based on a parameterized table name?

My main goal is two fold, one, get away from the long string as dynamic SQL and two, easier maintenance and debugging. I would like to think in the more current version of SQL Server from SQL Server 2016/2017 and on, this issue is addressed.

Your thoughts and suggestions is greatly appreciated.

~G

Comment: You cannot parametrise an object, it has to be a literal. This means you have to use dynamic SQL and **safely** inject the value (the above does not). Then you need to use `sys.sp_executesql` to execute and pass the parameters for any other variables to it. Have a look at [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql) where I cover a lot of considerations you need to take.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a synonym for the table and simply change the synonym every quarter? But it sounds like there is far more complicated logic for generating the correct query than simply swapping table names - so maybe your efforts are better spent elsewhere.

Comment: On 64-bit servers, the size of the dynamic SQL string is limited to 2 GB, the maximum size of nvarchar(max), so I wouldn't about that.

Comment: It's not any different on 32bit instances, @Piotr, it's still 2GB, or 1Billion~ characters.

Comment: Guys, I just did a little more research and I came across this:

https://codingsight.com/passing-data-table-as-parameter-to-stored-procedures/


curious to know if that would work, it seem it would...Your thoughts?  It's just so wonky that with one missing quote, things just blows in dynamic sql.

Comment: @Larnu, you said it man, "...a pain to debug if written poorly..."  It's like following behind a herd and you don't know what you will step on next.

Comment: *"t's just so wonky that with one missing quote, things just blows in dynamic sql."* That isn't just the case with dynamic SQL. `SELECT CONCAT('a, MT.MyColumn) FROM MyTable MT;` will fail too.

Comment: Which is why it's so important you write Dynamic SQL well as well. Formatting is just as important in a dynamic statement as it is in a non-dynamic one. I go on (in that article) to say *"One common reason I hear for why people don’t use dynamic SQL is because it’s difficult to troubleshoot. I personally find this a little untrue. Poorly written and/or formatted dynamic SQL is difficult to troubleshoot, but then the same is true for poorly written SQL in general."*.

Comment: Switching table name looks like some kind of https://www.brentozar.com/sql/table-partitioning-resources. Keep in mind it's enterprise feature. You could consider poor's man partitioning (search that fraze), whitch maybe someone was trying before you.

Comment: @Tomasito  Table and index partitioning is available in every edition of SQL Server 2016 SP1 and later, including Azure SQL Database.

Answer (score 0):

> So each quarter when a call is made out to these stored procedures, it comes with the actual table name passed as a parameter and then the dynamic SQL concatenates the table name.

You could change the procedure to codegen other stored procedures instead of running dynamic SQL.  EG:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE admin.RegenerateProcedures @tableName
as
begin

    declare @ddl nvarchar(max) = '
create or alter procedure dbo.SomeProc
as
begin
           SELECT......
            FROM dbo.' + quotename(@tableName) +  '
            WHERE.....   
            GROUP BY....
end
' 
     EXEC ( @ddl )
. . .
end
 GO
```

Comment: `EXEC (@DDL)` isn't a great idea. It promotes not parametrising the dynamic statement.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support parameters in DDL.

Comment: That isn't what I said... I said that use of `EXEC(@SQL)` or(`EXEC(@DDL)`, `EXEC(@SomeVariableCotntainingSQL)`) promotes not parametrising the dynamic statement. Use `sys.sp_executesql`.